# add text in input fields when user select the data from autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

> when user search in the input fields list autocomplete using ajax problem is click on the text than text not add in input field because data comes dynamically e.g i write lenova when i click it cannot set in the input fields

**index.php**

```
<div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="inputSuccess">Search Here....</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess" name="name" onkeyup="autosearch(this.value)" >
    <div class="result" style="width:100%;z-index:100;position: relative;"> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess" name="name" onkeyup="autosearch(this.value)" >
    <div class="result" style="width:100%;z-index:100;position: relative;"> 

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
<script>
 function autosearch(name){

$.ajax({
    url:"ajax.php",
    type:'post',
    data:{name:name},
    success:function(result){
        $('.result').html(result);
    }
   });
}

 </script>
 <script>

 $(document).ready(function()
 {
    $(".result > p").click(function()
    {
        var va1 = $(this).val();
        $("inputSuccess").val(va1); 


    });
});
 </script>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php 

$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$query ="select * from autosearch where autosearch_name like '".$name."%'";
$rs = mysql_query($query,$conn) or die("failed".mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){


<div style="border: 1px solid #ccc;width:100%;" >

            <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-decoration: none;" ><div style="width:20%; float:left ;text-decoration: none">
                <img src="image/<?php echo $data['autosearch_image']; ?>" width="80px;" ></div>
                <div style="width:80%;">
                    <p><?php echo $data['autosearch_name']; ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </a>
    </div>

 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use AutoComplete like this:

```
              $("#inputSuccess").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "someurl",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.something
                                Name: item.somethingelse,

                            };
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 3
        });

             $("#inputSuccess").on("autocompleteselect", function (event, ui) {

           $("#someelement").val(data.whatever);   
        });
```

Comment: patrick i am looking cutom autocomplete without any jquery library